# Receiving a Parse Error connecting to Monday.com

Tags: graphql, monday.com

I have a Monday.com board and can query the column names fine (1st code block below). But when I try to query the column values I get:

> “message”: “Parse error on "ids" (IDENTIFIER) at [1, 14]”

(2nd code block below). Any help is appreciated.

```
{
    “query”:
    “query boards(ids: 6035791171) {items {column_values {column {id title} id type value}}}”
}
```

```
{
    “query”:
    “query boards(ids: 6035791171) {items(limit: 50) {column_values(ids:[name, project_owner]) {title value}}}”
}
```